# How to return early and schedule an I/O operation during an ASP.NET MVC request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, background-process

I am building a ASP.NET MVC 4.0 application which renders images. During a request, the program checks if the image exists in a SQLite DB, which I use for caching previously rendered images.

If the image does not exist, it is

1. being rendered (based on data coming from various sources)
2. stored in SQLite
3. streamed back to the client

I would like to move step #2 in a background task so that the client does not have to wait for the I/O operation to complete.

Since the rendering process is CPU intensive, I wouldn't want to re-render the image in some windows service. I would like to be able to store the memory stream, in a non blocking way.

Comment: May be worth checking out asynchronous operations using .net 4 async/await. Using these a call to store an image in SQLite won't block the UI thread, which you can use to render the image without having to wait for I/O operations.

Comment: The image has to be rendered before being stored. Plus the async / await pattern won't make the HTTP request return early (before the image is persisted), will it?